# I need to display the salary of an agent's supervisor

Tags: sql, ms-access

[This is the Agent table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pDhN.png)

I was asked to do the following:

Create an SQL statement that will list the policy number of each policy, together with the name of the person insured by the policy ***and the salary of the supervisor of the agent that sold this policy.***  The heading for the column with the supervisor’s salary should be “Salary of Agent Supervisor”.  Policies should only appear in the list if they were not sold by an agent who is a manager.

My answer: (The only part that I cannot get write is the supervisor's salary)

```
SELECT PolicyNo, InsuredName, salary AS [Salary of Agent Supervisor]
FROM Agent,
     Policy,
     Insured
WHERE Agent.AgentNo = policy.AgentNo
  AND Policy.InsuredNo = Insured.InsuredNo
  AND Function <> "Manager"
```

The salaries and supervisors only exist in the Agent table and I am not allowed to use a sub-query

Answer (score 0):

You need to join the agent table to itself in order to link the supervisor to the agent:

```
SELECT Agent.PolicyNo, InsuredName, Supervisors.salary AS [Salary of Agent Supervisor]
FROM Agent,
     Agent AS Supervisors
     Policy,
     Insured
WHERE Agent.AgentNo = policy.AgentNo
  AND Agent.Supervisor = Supervisors.AgentNo
  AND Policy.InsuredNo = Insured.InsuredNo
  AND Agent.Function <> "Manager"
```